# ASP.net For Loop Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, loops, for-loop

I have a problem with a For loop, it looks like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        //for (int i = 0; i < System.Math.Min(dt.Rows.Count, 3); i++)
        {
            string date = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[i]["date"]).ToShortDateString();
            schedule[date] = (schedule[date] != null ? schedule[date].ToString() : "")    + Server.HtmlEncode(dt.Rows[i]["todo"].ToString()) + "<br />" + dt.Rows[i]["time"].ToString() + "<br />";
        }
        return schedule;
```

It's for a Calendar that I have made with an asp.net calendar control.
It loops through all records into my Database and gives back my Schedule (records of that date) but I dont want to show more than 3 lines of text that you can add to the calendar(database record). Have you any idea how i can do this ?

Thank you, kind regards, The Designer

Comment: What's wrong with the commented out code?

Comment: If i use that one i get just only 3 records back from the database so what it does is just give me 3 months back :P , so it only show 3 dates into my whole calendar and what i want is not more than 3 records in one Calendar day for each day. ty George

Comment: Sorry for my crappy english Dutch man here :)

Comment: This kind of problem is usually best solved with a SQL query that filters out the correct records from the database directly.

Comment: Thats a way aswell ty Anders Abel but i want it to keep it abit simple :)

Answer (score 2):

You could maintain a count of the number of lines you've added for each date:

```
Dictionary<string, int> schedulesDateCount = new Dictionary<string, int>();

for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    string date = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[i]["date"]).ToShortDateString();

    if(!schedulesDateCount.ContainsKey(date))
        schedulesDateCount[date] = 0;

    if(schedulesDateCount[date] < 3)
    {
        schedule[date] = (schedule[date] != null ? schedule[date].ToString() : "")    + Server.HtmlEncode(dt.Rows[i]["todo"].ToString()) + "<br />" + dt.Rows[i]["time"].ToString() + "<br />";
        schedulesDateCount[date] = schedulesDateCount[date] + 1;
    }
}
return schedule;
```

Comment: @George Duckett I think you should replace the `.HasKey` method with the `.ContainsKey` Method if(!schedulesDateCount.HasKey(date)) schedulesDateCount[date] = 0; Will be: if(!schedulesDateCount.ContainsKey(date)) schedulesDateCount[date] = 0; Then it should work!